# Char to Unicode in Python

Tags: python, char

I have went through the document of Python 3.8 and few website where it says str corresponds to former unicode type on Python 2 and bytes roughly corresponds to the former str type (for the bytes part) on Python 2.
I have also gone through codecs module in python.
I am trying to convert user input in to format similar to "\u0025\u0027". Could some one help me guide me on this. 
Example if User inputs "a ' Union Select 1,Null,Null information_schema.tables--" it should get converted to "\u0061\u0020\u0027\u0020\u0055\u006E\u0069\u006F\u006E\u0020\u0053\u0065\u006C\u0065\u0063\u0074\u0020\u0031\u002C\u004E\u0075\u006C\u006C\u002C\u004E\u0075\u006C\u006C\u0020\u0069\u006E\u0066\u006F\u0072\u006D\u0061\u0074\u0069\u006F\u006E\u005F\u0073\u0063\u0068\u0065\u006D\u0061\u002E\u0074\u0061\u0062\u006C\u0065\u0073\u002D\u002D"
The above conversion is from [Cyberchef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Escape_Unicode_Characters(%27%5C%5Cu%27,true,4,true)) where I have selected "Escape Unicode Character" with Padding 4

Regards

Comment: So which version of python are you wanting to use now? I ask because in Python 3, `"\u0061"` is the same as `"a"` so it is not meaningful to "convert" between them. Unless you meant the raw string `r"\u0061"`?

Comment: Yep, it's not clear what requirements you have on the results. For a starter, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, think about observable things which you describe here, because as alani noticed, `print("\u0061")` will give you the same output as `print("a")`.

Comment: If you're doing this to prevent SQL injection, you're on the wrong track…